# restrict object modifications

Tags: php, object, setter

I have a PHP object with an id that should not be changed, except in one specific context, when a specific method is called. But this method is outside the object class and can't inherit. I don't know what's the better way to do this properly, how can I "check" if the object setter is called by the right method, to avoid abuses?

Thanks in advance for your help

edit: here is an example:

```
<?php

class myClass {

private $id;
private $var1;
private $var2;


private function setId($id){
    //this must be accessible only when calling "secureSetId()" from class "secureClass"
    $this->id = $id;

}


public function setVar1{
    //this is a public function...

}

...

}

class secureClass {


private function secureSetId($id){

    //this is accessible only here, but how to call private function "setId" from class "myClass"?

}

...

}

?>
```

Comment: debug_backtrace() is one solution, but I don't know if it's a good as it costs some performance...

Comment: Show some code and an example

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

interface SimpleMyClass {
  public function setVar1($value);
  public function setVar2($value);
}

interface SecureMyClass extends SimpleMyClass {
  public function setId($id);
}

class MyClass implements SecureMyClass {
  private $id;  
  private $var1;
  private $var2;

  public function setVar1($value) { /* ... */ }
  public function setVar2($value) { /* ... */ }
  public function setId($id) { /* setting id */ }
}

// classes that use "different versions" of MyClass

class SecureOtherClass {
  public function setMyClass(SecureMyClass $my) {  /* this class is able to set id of MyClass */ }
}

class SimpleOtherClass {
  public function setMyClass(SimpleMyClass $my) { /* this class uses simple version of MyClass */ }
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced but I'm not sure, if I do something like this: $myClass MyClass = new MyClass(), and then $myClass->setId(7), I can do it everywhere... no? because setId() is public

Comment: @theplayer777 Yes, but if you separate objects creation from mannipulation, you'll get proper code. Of course you can force setting  Id even on SimpleMyClass object but then you will break the method's "contract". Actually this method works fine with strong-typed languages, in PHP you can overcome some limitations.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should change the architecture then, because I use the id of my object to test if it must be inserted or updated in the database when I call the method persist(). If the object has an id, this means that he comes from the database so its just an update. If it has no id, then it's a new object. So if we can easily change the id, this could be a problem if not handled...

Comment: getId() method can be added to the SimpleMyClass interface, so every method that takes SimpleMyClass object can read id and insert/update object. Only secureClass's methods operates on SecureMyClass objects so only they can contain setId() calls.